# Not outputting any values

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code seems not to be working properly. My goal is for the year and location to match up in the same row, and print out the information associated with that row. My code is posted below as well as the excel sheet for reading the data.

[image: Excel Sheet]

```
LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\Data_2016.csv' # CSV File to Read

with open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE) as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     mydict={}
     for row in reader:
         Year=row['Year']
         Busnum=row['Busnum']
         Area=row['Area']
         Power=row['Power']
         TLA=row['TLA']
         Location=row['Location']
         Yearlink=row['Yearlink']
         From=row['From']
         To=row['To']
         Max=row['Max']
         Min=row['Min']
year = raw_input("Please Select Year of Study: ") 
print("\n")

commands = ["Millwood-Buchanan", "Astoria-East-Corona", "Bronx", "DUNWOODIE-North-Sherman_Creek",
        "Vernon", "Greenwood-StatenIsland","West_49th","East_13th","Staten_Island","East_River",
        "East_View","DUNWOODIE-SOUTH","Corona-Jamaica","Astoria-East-Corona-Jamaica",
        "Astoria-West-Queensbridge-Vernon","Astoria-West-Queensbridge"]
max_columns = 50

for index, commands in enumerate(commands):
    stars_amount = max(max_columns - len(commands), 0)
    row = "# {} {}({})".format(commands, "." * stars_amount, index + 1)
    print(row)

 location=raw_input(" \n The list above show the TLA Pockets as well as the ID numbers assigned to them ()\n\n Please enter the ID #: ")
 print("\n")

if year==Year and location==Location:  
   mydict=[Busnum,Area,Power]

print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
print("\n")

   for Busnum,Area,Power in mydict:
    Power= float(scaled_power)
    Busnum = int(busnum)
    print('Bus #: %d\t' % Busnum ,'Area Station: %s\t'% Area,'New Load Total: %d MW\t' % Power)
```

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific as to "not to be working properly" means.

Comment: Its outputting only the input statements